# Getting errors when parsing values

Tags: java, android

I'm getting errors when i'm trying to parse the datas.

The program is to retrieve the datas from database and parse it to the main menu where the RecycleView lists out the datas such as name,username,image and description.

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g30Q9KHubTU

This is the code with errors.

DataParser.java

```
public class DataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> { //<<<line 22

Context c;
String jsonData;
RecyclerView rv;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

public DataParser(Context c, String jsonData, RecyclerView rv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    this.rv = rv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait.");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    super.onPostExecute(success);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(success)  //<<<line 59
    {
        //bind
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(c,items);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to parse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

private Boolean parseData()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo;

        items.clear();
        Item item;

        for(int i = 0; i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int itemid = jo.getInt("itemid");
            String imagepath = jo.getString("imagepath");
            String itemname = jo.getString("itemname");
            String username = jo.getString("username");
            String itemdesc = jo.getString("itemdesc");

            item = new Item();

            item.setId(itemid);
            item.setItemname(itemname);
            item.setUsername(username);
            item.setItemdesc(itemdesc);
            item.setImagepath(imagepath);

            items.add(item);

        }

        return true;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}




}
```

These are the errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference

at chengweifeng1132701116.fyp.m_MySQL.DataParser.onPostExecute(DataParser.java:59)

at chengweifeng1132701116.fyp.m_MySQL.DataParser.onPostExecute(DataParser.java:22)
```

Comment: Its because you are returning `null` in your `doInBackground` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are always returning `null` from `doInBackground`. So, your `success` variable is always null in `onPostExecute()`. Have the appropriate logic for parsing inside `doInBackground` and based on whether it was successful or not, return true or false.